# PlantUML deliverable/milestone is not positioned at end of milestone

Tags: gantt-chart, plantuml, milestone

I specify a milestone to occur at the end of an activity, with:

```
[<size:30>Platform Planning Buffer] as [1_3] lasts 30 days
[<size:30>First Customer Usage - first_customer_usage] as [first_customer_usage] happens at [1_3]'s end
```

However, it is positioned at somewhere before the start of that activity, (on a new line between purple and yellow):

[image]

I expect this is because that specific activity does not have a follow-up.

The full UML file is:

```
@startgantt
project starts the 2022/10-01
saturday are closed
sunday are closed
skinparam classFontSize 100

[<size:30>Develop protocol] as [0] lasts 120 days
[<size:30>On-chain: Solidty+VRF] as [0_0] lasts 60 days
[<size:30>Git integration: Tellor] as [0_1] lasts 90 days
[<size:30>Git integration: Chainlink] as [0_2] lasts 90 days
[<size:30>Support all languages - support_all_languages] as [support_all_languages] happens at [0_2]'s end
[<size:30>Alternative Chains] as [0_3] lasts 90 days
[<size:30>(Decentralised) Continuous integration] as [0_2_0] lasts 30 days
[<size:30>Security & Robustness] as [0_2_1] lasts 60 days

[<size:30>Platform & ecosystem] as [1] lasts 120 days
[<size:30>Website] as [1_0] lasts 50 days
[<size:30>API] as [1_0_0] lasts 50 days
[<size:30>GUI] as [1_0_1] lasts 50 days
[<size:30>Forum] as [1_0_2] lasts 10 days
[<size:30>Marketing platform] as [1_1] lasts 30 days
[<size:30>Subsidize bounties] as [1_2] lasts 10 days
[<size:30>Platform Planning Buffer] as [1_3] lasts 30 days
[<size:30>First Customer Usage - first_customer_usage] as [first_customer_usage] happens at [1_3]'s end

[<size:30>Launch company] as [2] lasts 150 days
[<size:30>Qualitative partner research] as [2_0] lasts 20 days
[<size:30>Establish organisation] as [2_1] lasts 80 days
[<size:30>Auditing] as [2_1_0] lasts 10 days
[<size:30>Hiring] as [2_1_1] lasts 20 days
[<size:30>Administration] as [2_1_2] lasts 10 days
[<size:30>Legal] as [2_1_3] lasts 20 days
[<size:30>Financial] as [2_1_4] lasts 20 days
[<size:30>Marketing] as [2_2] lasts 30 days
[<size:30>Organisation Planning Buffer ] as [2_3] lasts 20 days

[0_0] starts at [0]'s start
[0_1] starts at [0]'s start
[0_2] starts at [0]'s start
[0_3] starts at [0]'s start
[0_2_0] starts at [0_3]'s end
[0_2_1] starts at [0_2_0]'s end
[1] starts at [0]'s start

[1_0] starts at [1]'s start
[1_1] starts at [1_0]'s end
[1_2] starts at [1_1]'s end
[1_3] starts at [1_2]'s end
[1_0_0] starts at [1_0]'s start
[1_0_1] starts at [0]'s start
[1_0_2] starts at [0]'s start
[2] starts at [0]'s start

[2_0] starts at [2]'s start
[2_1] starts at [2_0]'s end
[2_2] starts at [2_1]'s end
[2_3] starts at [2_2]'s end
[2_1_0] starts at [2_1]'s start
[2_1_1] starts at [2_1_0]'s end
[2_1_2] starts at [2_1_1]'s end
[2_1_3] starts at [2_1_2]'s end
[2_1_4] starts at [2_1_3]'s end

[0]  is colored in Green
[0_0]  is colored in Green
[0_1]  is colored in Green
[0_2]  is colored in Green
[0_3]  is colored in Green
[0_2_0]  is colored in Green
[0_2_1]  is colored in Green


[1]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_0]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_0_0]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_0_1]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_0_2]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_1]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_2]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_3]  is colored in DarkOrchid


[2]  is colored in Yellow
[2_0]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1_0]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1_1]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1_2]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1_3]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1_4]  is colored in Yellow
[2_2]  is colored in Yellow
[2_3]  is colored in Yellow


'[Develop protocol]  takes: 120[days] equating to:960[hours] and costs:0 per hour, yielding activity costs:0 Euros.
'[On-chain: Solidty+VRF]  takes: 60[days] equating to:480[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:36480 Euros.
'[Git integration: Tellor]  takes: 90[days] equating to:720[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:54720 Euros.
'[Git integration: Chainlink]  takes: 90[days] equating to:720[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:54720 Euros.
'[Alternative Chains]  takes: 90[days] equating to:720[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:54720 Euros.
'[(Decentralised) Continuous integration]  takes: 30[days] equating to:240[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:18240 Euros.
'[Security & Robustness]  takes: 60[days] equating to:480[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:36480 Euros.


'[Platform & ecosystem]  takes: 120[days] equating to:960[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:39360 Euros.
'[Website]  takes: 50[days] equating to:400[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:16400 Euros.
'[API]  takes: 50[days] equating to:400[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:16400 Euros.
'[GUI]  takes: 50[days] equating to:400[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:16400 Euros.
'[Forum]  takes: 10[days] equating to:80[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:3280 Euros.
'[Marketing platform]  takes: 30[days] equating to:240[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:9840 Euros.
'[Subsidize bounties]  takes: 10[days] equating to:80[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:3280 Euros.
'[Platform Planning Buffer]  takes: 30[days] equating to:240[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:9840 Euros.


'[Launch company]  takes: 150[days] equating to:1200[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:43200 Euros.
'[Qualitative partner research]  takes: 20[days] equating to:160[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:5760 Euros.
'[Establish organisation]  takes: 80[days] equating to:640[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:23040 Euros.
'[Auditing]  takes: 10[days] equating to:80[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:2880 Euros.
'[Hiring]  takes: 20[days] equating to:160[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:5760 Euros.
'[Administration]  takes: 10[days] equating to:80[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:2880 Euros.
'[Legal]  takes: 20[days] equating to:160[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:5760 Euros.
'[Financial]  takes: 20[days] equating to:160[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:5760 Euros.
'[Marketing]  takes: 30[days] equating to:240[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:8640 Euros.
'[Organisation Planning Buffer ]  takes: 20[days] equating to:160[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:5760 Euros.

[<size:30>Complete CI deployment - complete_ci_deployment] as [complete_ci_deployment] happens  2022-12-01
@endgantt
```

### Question

How can I ensure the deliverable/milestone is actually located at the end of the activity (Without manually computing the end date of the activity)?

Comment: It's not related to your question, but you could eliminate a lot of repetitive formatting, e.g. `<size:30>` by using the `<style>` feature for Gantt. There are examples in https://plantuml.com/guide in section 16.18.2

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! For completeness this Gantt UML is automatically generated in Python, and I'm currently not running millions of these, so for now I prefer to allocate my efforts towards other priorities. Yet it is nice to know the same result can be obtained through less verbose means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature, but I think that the milestone when it's declared is miscalculating its date, probably because the other dates haven't been calculated.

The fix was to define only its "duration" (which is a kind of hack for a milestone) to 0, as well as its `as [name]` as before.

```
[<size:30>First Customer Usage - first_customer_usage] as [first_customer_usage] lasts 0 days
```

Later, after the other dependency links are specified, you can specify its date using its `as` reference.

```
[first_customer_usage] happens at [1_3]'s end
```

Here's the result:

[image]

```
@startgantt
project starts the 2022/10-01
saturday are closed
sunday are closed
skinparam classFontSize 100

[<size:30>Develop protocol] as [0] lasts 120 days
[<size:30>On-chain: Solidty+VRF] as [0_0] lasts 60 days
[<size:30>Git integration: Tellor] as [0_1] lasts 90 days
[<size:30>Git integration: Chainlink] as [0_2] lasts 90 days
[<size:30>Support all languages - support_all_languages] as [support_all_languages] happens at [0_2]'s end
[<size:30>Alternative Chains] as [0_3] lasts 90 days
[<size:30>(Decentralised) Continuous integration] as [0_2_0] lasts 30 days
[<size:30>Security & Robustness] as [0_2_1] lasts 60 days

[<size:30>Platform & ecosystem] as [1] lasts 120 days
[<size:30>Website] as [1_0] lasts 50 days
[<size:30>API] as [1_0_0] lasts 50 days
[<size:30>GUI] as [1_0_1] lasts 50 days
[<size:30>Forum] as [1_0_2] lasts 10 days
[<size:30>Marketing platform] as [1_1] lasts 30 days
[<size:30>Subsidize bounties] as [1_2] lasts 10 days
[<size:30>Platform Planning Buffer] as [1_3] lasts 30 days
[<size:30>First Customer Usage - first_customer_usage] as [first_customer_usage] lasts 0 days

[<size:30>Launch company] as [2] lasts 150 days
[<size:30>Qualitative partner research] as [2_0] lasts 20 days
[<size:30>Establish organisation] as [2_1] lasts 80 days
[<size:30>Auditing] as [2_1_0] lasts 10 days
[<size:30>Hiring] as [2_1_1] lasts 20 days
[<size:30>Administration] as [2_1_2] lasts 10 days
[<size:30>Legal] as [2_1_3] lasts 20 days
[<size:30>Financial] as [2_1_4] lasts 20 days
[<size:30>Marketing] as [2_2] lasts 30 days
[<size:30>Organisation Planning Buffer ] as [2_3] lasts 20 days

[0_0] starts at [0]'s start
[0_1] starts at [0]'s start
[0_2] starts at [0]'s start
[0_3] starts at [0]'s start
[0_2_0] starts at [0_3]'s end
[0_2_1] starts at [0_2_0]'s end
[1] starts at [0]'s start

[1_0] starts at [1]'s start
[1_1] starts at [1_0]'s end
[1_2] starts at [1_1]'s end
[1_3] starts at [1_2]'s end
[1_0_0] starts at [1_0]'s start
[1_0_1] starts at [0]'s start
[1_0_2] starts at [0]'s start
[2] starts at [0]'s start

[2_0] starts at [2]'s start
[2_1] starts at [2_0]'s end
[2_2] starts at [2_1]'s end
[2_3] starts at [2_2]'s end
[2_1_0] starts at [2_1]'s start
[2_1_1] starts at [2_1_0]'s end
[2_1_2] starts at [2_1_1]'s end
[2_1_3] starts at [2_1_2]'s end
[2_1_4] starts at [2_1_3]'s end

[0]  is colored in Green
[0_0]  is colored in Green
[0_1]  is colored in Green
[0_2]  is colored in Green
[0_3]  is colored in Green
[0_2_0]  is colored in Green
[0_2_1]  is colored in Green


[1]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_0]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_0_0]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_0_1]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_0_2]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_1]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_2]  is colored in DarkOrchid
[1_3]  is colored in DarkOrchid


[2]  is colored in Yellow
[2_0]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1_0]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1_1]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1_2]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1_3]  is colored in Yellow
[2_1_4]  is colored in Yellow
[2_2]  is colored in Yellow
[2_3]  is colored in Yellow

[first_customer_usage] happens at [1_3]'s end


'[Develop protocol]  takes: 120[days] equating to:960[hours] and costs:0 per hour, yielding activity costs:0 Euros.
'[On-chain: Solidty+VRF]  takes: 60[days] equating to:480[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:36480 Euros.
'[Git integration: Tellor]  takes: 90[days] equating to:720[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:54720 Euros.
'[Git integration: Chainlink]  takes: 90[days] equating to:720[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:54720 Euros.
'[Alternative Chains]  takes: 90[days] equating to:720[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:54720 Euros.
'[(Decentralised) Continuous integration]  takes: 30[days] equating to:240[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:18240 Euros.
'[Security & Robustness]  takes: 60[days] equating to:480[hours] and costs:76 per hour, yielding activity costs:36480 Euros.


'[Platform & ecosystem]  takes: 120[days] equating to:960[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:39360 Euros.
'[Website]  takes: 50[days] equating to:400[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:16400 Euros.
'[API]  takes: 50[days] equating to:400[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:16400 Euros.
'[GUI]  takes: 50[days] equating to:400[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:16400 Euros.
'[Forum]  takes: 10[days] equating to:80[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:3280 Euros.
'[Marketing platform]  takes: 30[days] equating to:240[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:9840 Euros.
'[Subsidize bounties]  takes: 10[days] equating to:80[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:3280 Euros.
'[Platform Planning Buffer]  takes: 30[days] equating to:240[hours] and costs:41 per hour, yielding activity costs:9840 Euros.


'[Launch company]  takes: 150[days] equating to:1200[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:43200 Euros.
'[Qualitative partner research]  takes: 20[days] equating to:160[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:5760 Euros.
'[Establish organisation]  takes: 80[days] equating to:640[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:23040 Euros.
'[Auditing]  takes: 10[days] equating to:80[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:2880 Euros.
'[Hiring]  takes: 20[days] equating to:160[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:5760 Euros.
'[Administration]  takes: 10[days] equating to:80[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:2880 Euros.
'[Legal]  takes: 20[days] equating to:160[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:5760 Euros.
'[Financial]  takes: 20[days] equating to:160[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:5760 Euros.
'[Marketing]  takes: 30[days] equating to:240[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:8640 Euros.
'[Organisation Planning Buffer ]  takes: 20[days] equating to:160[hours] and costs:36 per hour, yielding activity costs:5760 Euros.

[<size:30>Complete CI deployment - complete_ci_deployment] as [complete_ci_deployment] happens  2022-12-01
@endgantt
```

Comment: That is a hack if I have ever seen one, yet an effective one, without visual artefacts. Thank you! I also appreciate your hypothesis on what is happening on what may cause the behaviour.

Comment: Of the hacks I've suggested on stackoverflow, this is the most elegantt. 